# CREATE TABLE and transactions

Tags: transaction, sybase-ase

Is there a way to use `CREATE TABLE` inside of a transaction in Sybase?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: @markp-fuso, ASE, latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about `Sybase ASE` ...

To allow DDL (eg, `create table`) to be performed within a transaction the DBA can configure the database (where the DDL is to be performed) with the following:

```
sp_dboption <dbname>,'ddl in tran',true
```

**NOTE**: `ddl in tran` == `true` is not recommended since this can lead to excessive blocking, and in some rare cases deadlocking, on system table activity

Comment: @mark-fuso, so if I am accessing the DB from c++ odbc or native client (either freeTDS or db-lib), I should check the return value of the function and just delete all previous commands, right?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about re: `function` and `all previous commands`; the (above) answer addresses how to allow DDL (eg, `create table`) inside of a txn; if you're having other issues I'd suggest asking a new question and be sure to provide details of the issue(s)